# Code repeats after questions are answered why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to create a small ATM program

I’m kind of stuck every time I choose checking‘s. The program should run by asking me how much I would like to take out, how much I would like to put in, and show my total amounts.

But when I run the program and answer the questions, it repeats itself again by asking how much would you like to take out. How can I fix that issue?

I have tried to break and also sys.exit(), but still I have not been able to fix the problem.

```
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image
import sys

# Our images
image = Image.open(“fargo.JPG”)
image.show()

image2 = Image.open(“load2.GIF”)

Press_button = input(“Welcome to Wells Fargo please input your pin:\n”)
print(“”)

if Press_button == "9476":
    image2.show()
    print("Please wait while we process information")
    sleep(2)
    print("What would you like to choose?")


ATM_class = ["1. Checkings", "2. Savings", "3. Deposit"]

sleep(1)
print(ATM_class[0])
print(ATM_class[1])
print(ATM_class[2])
print("")

Section = input("Please choose section: ")
print("")


# Main ATM functions
#Section-1


def bank():
    Checkings = 100
    Savings = 100
    Checkings_TO = int(input("How much would you like to take out: " + "$"))
    x = Checkings_TO

    Checkings_PI = int(input("How much would you like to put in: " + "$"))
    y = Checkings_PI


    if Section == ("Checkings"):
            return(int(input("How much would you like to take out: " + "$")))

            return(int(input("How much would you like to put in: ")))

            return("Here is your total: " + "$" + str(x))
            print(sys.exit())


    if Section == ("Savings"):
        return(int(input("How much would you like to take out: " + "$")))
        return(int(input("How much would you like to put in: ")))
        return("Here is your total: " + "$" + str(y))

print(("Here take your money, please: " + "$" +(str(bank()))))
#print(sys.exit())
```

Comment: Please be consistent in your naming. Also, you can't have multiple return statements. The function will exit on the first return.

Comment: Please show example! .-.

Comment: In your own words, how do you expect `return` to work?

Comment: "But when I run the program and answer the questions it repeats itself again" Look at your code. On how many lines do you have the code, `int(input("How much would you like to take out: " + "$"))`? Are you expecting more than one of those lines of code to be reached? Are you expecting it to do something different each time? Why?

Comment: Yes so once I choose Checkings 3 questions will pop up and once the question is answered the next question will pop up next which will be “How much would you like to put in?” So yes I am expected to do something different on each question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions are repeated because you are asking them after `def bank`:

```
def bank():
    Checkings = 100
    Savings = 100
    Checkings_TO = int(input("How much would you like to take out: " + "$")) #Here
    x = Checkings_TO
    Checkings_PI = int(input("How much would you like to put in: " + "$")) #Here
    y = Checkings_PI
```

And then one more time if one of the *if* statements is true.

Also you should change the usage of return in your function. I don't know if it was what you wanted to achieve, but I think it should be like this:

```
if Section == ("Checkings"):
    how_much_take = int(input("How much would you like to take out: " + "$"))
    how_much_put = (int(input("How much would you like to put in: ")))
    print ("Here is your total: " + "$" + str(x))

if Section == ("Savings"):
    how_much_take = int(input("How much would you like to take out: " + "$"))
    how_much_put = (int(input("How much would you like to put in: ")))
    print ("Here is your total: " + "$" + str(y))
```

Comment: So it works only thing am wondering is why it returns None when I call the function?

Comment: Where it returns None ? In my version that i posted here is no return statement. All the function usage is inside the function body